# HREF an IP Address

Tags: php, html, href

Good Day, 
I have a computer serverA (10.31.5.206) and another serverB(10.31.5.187). Server A contains files shared over the intranet in my workplace, while server B has a landing page. By using firefox, i'm able to access the files by typing in "10.31.5.206/data" into the url on firefox. However, if i key in the same link in landing page on server B, the browser is accessing it as "10.31.5.187/10.31.5.206/data". This makes it unable to access files in 10.31.5.206/data. Is there any error in my coding? My href coding goes like this:

```
    <td width="325"><center><a href="10.31.5.206/data"><input type="image" name="TM's folder" id="TM's folder" src="image/2.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Without the protocol in the URL it looks like a relative URL to the browser. Add `http://` to the URL to make it resolve properly.

```
<td width="325"><center><a href="http://10.31.5.206/data"><input type="image" name="TM's folder" id="TM's folder" src="image/2.png" /></a>
```